# SQL Server Select Top records from one table in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with thousands of keywords. I would like to isolate the top 25 negative keywords in that table and then from those top keywords create a join to find the sentences linked to those keywords in another table. The final result will be `id_file`, `sentence_id`, `sentiment`, `sentence`, `token`. Both tables have the tokens.

The token table (`tbl_token`) has the following columns:

```
id_file, sentence_id, sentiment, token
```

The filters to isolate the top 25 from `tbl_token` are as follows:

```
id_file = 3, sentiment = 'negative'
```

The sentence table (`tbl_sentence`) has the following columns:

```
id_file, sentence_id, sentiment, **sentence**, token
```

The sentence_id in both tables have a one to many relationship so a join on those will pull out the sentences. The tokens from the top query exist in `tbl_sentence`.

My current solution is to first run a top 25 from `tbl_token` for the same filters as above, count token, sort it in descending order.

```
SELECT TOP (25) 
    COUNT(token) AS Count, token
FROM
    tbl_token
GROUP BY 
    token, sentiment, id_file
HAVING     
    (sentiment = N'negative') AND (id_file = 3)
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(token) DESC
```

Then I link that to all the tokens in a view which has the `sentence_id`. Then I can link `sentence_id` from the view to `tbl_sentence` to isolate the sentences based on the top 25 negative keywords.

This works but I am a just wondering if this can be done in one stored procedure.

Comment: just show the result you want..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple query using a `SELECT TOP` with an `INNER JOIN`. Have you researched JOINS? Also, are you sure you don't mean one to many? If the token appears in multiple sentences then you will only get the first 25 results as you specified instead of multiple matches of the top 25 tokens. The `ORDER BY` is relatively important as the TOP 25 will not always be in a predictable order unless you specify a rank order.

```
SELECT TOP 25 
    ts.id_file, 
    ts.sentence_id, 
    ts.sentiment, 
    ts.sentence, 
    ts.token
FROM
  tbl_token tt 
  INNER JOIN tbl_sentence ts on ts.sentence_id=tt.sentence_id
WHERE
   tt.id_file=3
   AND
   tt.sentiment='negative'
ORDER BY
    tt.SomeFieldToRank25ByDateOrPriority
```

**Edited for One to Many!**

```
SELECT
    ts.id_file, 
    ts.sentence_id, 
    ts.sentiment, 
    ts.sentence, 
    ts.token
    SentenceCount=COUNT(*)
FROM
 ( 
    SELECT TOP 25 
        tt.sentence_id
    FROM 
        tbl_token tt 
    WHERE
       tt.id_file=3
       AND
       tt.sentiment='negative'
    ORDER BY
        tt.SomeFieldToRank25ByDateOrPriority
)AS X
INNER JOIN tbl_sentence ts on ts.sentence_id=x.sentence_id
GROUP BY
    ts.id_file, 
    ts.sentence_id, 
    ts.sentiment, 
    ts.sentence, 
    ts.token
```

Comment: Normally I would order by the count of tokens, so wouldn't this need to have a group by with a count of token in desc order.  The above doesn't isolate the top 25 keywords from the thousands.  I added the top 25 query I use today (see above).

Comment: I was confused. If you mean one token can be in multiple sentences then you will need to select from a top 25 subquery and THEN inner join with your other table.

Comment: Tokens are in there respective columns. Yes currently I have a sub query and then a View to find the sentences. I would like to get rid of the view, if possible, speed is okay, but I could have millions of records and that view could slow things down.

Comment: Millions and even billions of records are manageable with proper design. The subquery will return in no time if your order by and select fields are indexed. The inner join will also be fast if token is an indexed fields in both tables.